# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while referencing Lambda code in AWS CDK code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am new to **AWS CDK**.

**Problem:** I'm trying to reference my lambda code into **CDK** code but 
it throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when I try to test it on **AWS Lambda Console**.

I have added some code for reference. The classes are present in same package.

`LambdaFunctionHandler` class :

**Lambda Code:**

```
package com.myorg;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    public String handleRequest(String event, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Received event: " + event);
        return "Hello from lambda "+event;

    }

}
```

**CDK code:**

```
package com.myorg;

import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Construct;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.Stack;
import software.amazon.awscdk.core.StackProps;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Code;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Function;
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Runtime;

public class CdkProjectStack extends Stack {
    public CdkProjectStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        this(scope, id, null);
    }

    public CdkProjectStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // The code that defines your stack goes here
        final Function hello = Function.Builder.create(this, "HelloHandler")
                .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_8)   
                .code(Code.fromAsset("src/main/java/com/myorg"))  
                .handler("com.myorg.LambdaFunctionHandler::handleRequest")        
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
START RequestId: 0fdf618c-1bfb-4905-9283-f6b4e34a6585 Version: $LATEST
Class not found: com.myorg.LambdaFunctionHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myorg.LambdaFunctionHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

Comment: Please add the error log.

Comment: @AnishB. please check now.

Comment: please add a sample project to test.

Comment: Your handler looks correct. Did you created the deployment package? Please follow guide at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html for more information

Comment: @MilanG I am trying to deploy it through CDK CLI. So, didnt created the deployment package.

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: Also, try to change to `public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, String>`

Comment: What do you mean, "didn't create a deployment package"?  It doesn't matter if you use the console or the CLI you need a Lambda packaged deployment.

Comment: @MilanG It fixed with deployment package. Thanks for helping it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after creating a Deployment Package.